# How to hide controls on video full screen while mouse is not moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I've made my own custom controls for my WEB videos. Now I need to hide my control if the video is on fullscreen mode and if the mouse is not moving.

So far I'm doing is this:

```
var fullscreen_or_not=0;
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', videoscreenmode, false);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', videoscreenmode, false);
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', videoscreenmode, false);

function videoscreenmode(){
    if(fullscreen_or_not==0){
        fullscreen_or_not=1;
        $('.controls').css("bottom","-65px");
        document.onmousemove = function(){
            $('.controls').css("bottom","0px");
            console.log("hey");
        }
    }else{
        fullscreen_or_not=0;
    }
}
```

FYI: I need to set controls bottom position to `-65px` if mouse is not moving otherwise to `0`.

But this didn't worked, also once the video enters full screen the event listener for `onmousemove` start and even if I get out of it back it still is listening and outputing me on console saying `hey`.

I would really appreciate if someone tell me how to set my controls (contained with div) bottom position to `-65px` if mouse is not moving on document full screen else set bottom position to `0px`.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Provide a working example link so someone can help.

Comment: Does 'hey' gets logged in your console?

Comment: @Roberrrt Yes if the video once enters fullscreen and then wither the video gets out or stay in it still outputs `hey` over and over.

Comment: Aren't your controls simply under your video in fullscreen?

Comment: @roberrt Normally my controls position in css is set to `-65px`. and mouse hover over the video it goes back to `0px`

Answer (score 3):

Might help others.

Simple and easy way:

```
var timeout = null;
$(video).on('mousemove', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('.controls').css("bottom","0px");
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.vidCE').css("bottom","-65px");
    }, 3000);
});
```